# Typecasting values in Sequel finders

Tags: ruby, casting, sequel

I have a model with a numeric status column, which is mapped to symbols by the model. This works well so far but I can not use the finder mechanism of sequel with this.

Lets take this model

```
class Task < Sequel::Model
  finder def self.by_status(status)
    where(status: status)
  end
end
```

With this example database:

```
DB.create_table(:tasks) { primary_key :id; Integer :status }
3.times {|n| DB[:tasks].insert(status: n) }
```

With this I can use `Task.first_by_status(2)` to receive the dataset. The query behind the finder is created by the Sequel::Dataset::PlaceholderLiteralizer mechanism.

When I add the Symbol mapping the model looks more like this:

```
class Task < Sequel::Model
  STATES = {
    0 => :new,
    1 => :busy,
    2 => :done,
    3 => :failed,
  }.freeze

  finder def self.by_status(status)
    where(status: status2id(status))
  end

  def status=(v)
    super self.class.status2id(v)
  end

  def status
    STATES.fetch(super)
  end

  def self.status2id(sym)
    sym = sym.downcase.to_sym
    STATES.key(sym)
  end
end
```

The modified finder method does not work anymore, because it passes a `Sequel::Dataset::PlaceholderLiteralizer::Argument` instance to `.status2id` in the recording phase.

Is there a way to modify the arguments while using this mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Sequel's `finder` method supports what you want to do.  Note that `finder` is only an optimization, you can certainly just do:

```
def first_by_status(status)
  by_status(status).first
end
```